# SQL Server 2012 query to compute calculations

Tags: math, sql-server-2012

I am building a query within SQL Server that is calculating scores we receive for our surveys. We have a column called overall_score, where the user inputs a number from 1-5 as a rating. I am trying to create a stored procedure that will calculate ratings based off the scores.

```
Score rating = (Total count of scores 4 and 5)/(Total number of responses) * 100
```

I have three separate select statements that create results I need, but when I go to combine them together my output is 0.

Can someone please guide me on what I am doing wrong here?

Separate SQL Statements:

```
SELECT count(overall_score) FROM Layer1_DataMerge WHERE overall_score = 4;  
SELECT count(overall_score) FROM Layer1_DataMerge WHERE overall_score = 5;  
SELECT count(overall_score) FROM Layer1_DataMerge;
```

Combined together:

```
SELECT distinct
(  
    (
        (SELECT count(overall_score) FROM Layer1_DataMerge WHERE Overall_Score = 4) +  
        (SELECT count(overall_score) FROM Layer1_DataMerge WHERE overall_score = 5)
    ) / (SELECT count(overall_score) FROM Layer1_DataMerge)
) AS CSAT  
FROM Layer1_DataMerge;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the *reason* you're getting zero is because you're doing *integer* division.  With integer division 1/3 = 0.   You need to convert to floating-point arithmetic, plus you can do it all in one query:

```
SELECT 100.0 * 
       (SUM(CASE WHEN overall_score = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       SUM(CASE WHEN overall_score = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) / 
       COUNT(overall_score)
```

or

```
SELECT 100.0 * 
       SUM(CASE WHEN overall_score IN (4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
       COUNT(overall_score)
```

To only show 2 decimals you can either cast to a numeric type with 2 decimals:

```
SELECT CAST(
         100.0 * 
         SUM(CASE WHEN overall_score IN (4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
         COUNT(overall_score)
       AS NUMERIC(5,2))
```

Or use STR to convert to a string:

```
SELECT STR(
         100.0 * 
         SUM(CASE WHEN overall_score IN (4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
         COUNT(overall_score)
       ,5,2)
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked, thank you so much. Now my only problem is I can't get the correct amount of decimals to place. I thought the results would only show the amount of decimals you place in your multiplier. When I use 100.0 or 100.00 I still get the same answer of 0.62044589450, I only want it to display 0.62....